# K-means issue with opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I hope you are having a good day.

I'm trying to use the k-means algorithm to segment the 19*19 intersections in a go board :

[image]

```
def segment_intersections_kmeans(pts, k=19**2, **kwargs):
    """Groups intersections based on position with k-means.

    Uses k-means on the coordinates of the angle on the unit circle 
    to segment `k` angles inside `lines`.
    """

    criteria = (cv.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS + cv.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER, 10, 1.0)
    flags = kwargs.get('flags', cv.KMEANS_RANDOM_CENTERS)
    attempts = kwargs.get('attempts', 100)

    pts = np.float32(pts)

    # run kmeans on the coords
    labels, centers = cv.kmeans(pts, k, None, criteria, attempts, flags)[1:]
    print("Labels \n" , labels, "\n", len(labels))
   

    labels = labels.reshape(-1)  # transpose to row vec

    # segment lines based on their kmeans label
    segmented = defaultdict(list)
    for i, line in enumerate(pts):
        segmented[labels[i]].append(line)
    segmented = list(segmented.values())
    return segmented
```

However, the result is quite far from what is expected...
You can see the centers of clusters plotted in green :

[image]

And there I plotted all clusters :

[image]

Would you have any ideas of what is wrong ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I do not think kmeans is appropriate with k=19**2. It is like not having any change from your input. kmeans is usually used with a low number for k. Your input is just black on brown. So only really two colors.  kmeans is not going to be spatially sensitive when you only have two colors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! The algorithm gets the coordinates of each cross (the brown board is shown only for visualization). Yes indeed, 19**2 might be too much for kmeans. Would you have an idea of an algorithm that could be more useful here ?

Comment: Threshold on black using cv2.inRange(). Apply morphology to remove the lines. Get contours of connectedComponents with stats. Then get the contour or blob centers.

Comment: untouched source picture please. -- 19**2 clusters shouldn't be a problem. and neither would "color". there is no color involved here, only coordinates (I hope). the issue is that your approach, finding corners and clustering them, might simply not work. I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Comment: Okay, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to get the grid coordinates in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the input as grayscale
- Otsu thresh
- Apply close morphology, then erode morphology
- Invert the morphology result
- Get contours
- Loop over each contour and find the centroid. Then draw the centroid on a copy of the input and print the centroids.
- Save results

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read the image
img = cv2.imread('grid.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# threshold on black
thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

# apply morphology close and open
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT , (5,5))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (7,7))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(morph, cv2.MORPH_ERODE, kernel)

# invert
morph = 255 - morph

# get contours
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]

# find centroids and draw circles on input
centers = img.copy()
centers = cv2.merge([centers,centers,centers])
for cntr in contours:
    M = cv2.moments(cntr)
    cx = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])
    cy = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
    x = round(cx)
    y = round(cy)
    r = 2
    cv2.circle(centers, (x,y), r, (0, 0, 255), 2)
    print("xcenter:", cx, "ycenter:", cy)       

# save results
cv2.imwrite('grid_theshold.jpg', thresh)
cv2.imwrite('grid_morphology.jpg', morph)
cv2.imwrite('grid_centers.jpg', centers)

# show results
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('morph', morph)
cv2.imshow('centers', centers)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Threshold image:

[image]

Morphology cleaned and inverted image:

[image]

Grid centers image:

[image]

Comment: that's not the original image though. you're working with a version that OP drew crosses into. applying morphology to an illustration strikes me as a roundabout way to get this done.

Comment: `@Christoph Rackwitz`  I could have use connectedComponentsWithStats but thought contours would be best.  The morphology was primarily to remove any residual lines left in the image and then recover the regions from too much decimation.  Would welcome seeing another approach if you have other suggestions.  I thought that was the original, since it was posted first and had no graphics on it.